# Xamarin forms UWP Stepper display error is occured. How to fix my code?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am using Stepper and Slider. My code is as below.
It works well on android and ios, but on uwp it has a display error.

(1) MainPage.xaml

```
        <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="12,12,12,12">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Slider x:Name="Slider1" Maximum="100" Minimum="1" ValueChanged="SliderChanged" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    MinimumTrackColor="LightPink" MaximumTrackColor="LightPink"/>
            <Stepper x:Name="Stepper1" Maximum="100" Minimum="1" Increment="1" 
                     ValueChanged="StepperChanged" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Value:" FontSize="Large"/>
            <Label x:Name="ShowValue" FontSize="Large"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

(2) MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Stepper1.Value = 50;
        Slider1.Value = 50;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    private void SliderChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stepper1.Value = e.NewValue;
        ShowValue.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
    }

    private void StepperChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider1.Value = e.NewValue;
        ShowValue.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Build UWP project.
2. Using Slider to Max
3. Using Slider to Min
4. Using Slider to Center

**Expected Behavior:**

Stepper shall be displayed like the following image.
[image]

**Actual Behavior:**

Stepper display error is occured. It looks like the value is Maximum and Minimum.
I can push "+" and "-" to change value, but the backcolor cannot be changed after the error.
[image]

**Basic Information**

Xamarin.Forms: 4.2.0.709249

Platform;UWP

Windows:10

Could you please tell me how to fix my code? Or this is an error on Xamarin forms uwp?

Comment: Hi zhi qin, I tested your code and I could reproduce your issue, I suppose this xamrin issue, I suggest you post this as a bug into Xamarin github.

Comment: Nico Zhu, Thank you for your reply. I have posted this issue.https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7361